# Javascript regular expression to add protocol to url string

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have an application to list some website details using JavaScript. There will be a link to website which is generated using JavaScript itself. Sometimes I will get my link as,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Website</a>
```

But sometimes it will be,

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com">Website</a>
```

In the second time the link is not working, there is no protocol.

So I am looking for a JavaScript regular expression function to add http:// if there in no protocol.

My code looks like,

```
var website_link = document.createElement("a"); 
website_link.innerHTML = "Website"; 
website_link.href = my_JSON_object.website;
website_link.target = "_blank"; 
profile.appendChild(website_link);
```

And no local links will come.

Comment: ^www.   replace with  ^http://www ?
though therer are sub-domain urls that have no www :)

Comment: You're trying to fix the problem too late. It's impossible to tell if "www.yahoo.com" is a local file (maybe missing) or a bad URL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/qXv7H/) link.

```
function setHttp(link) {
    if (link.search(/^http[s]?\:\/\//) == -1) {
        link = 'http://' + link;
    }
    return link;
}
alert(setHttp("www.google.com"));
alert(setHttp("http://www.google.com/"));
```

In your code it will be like:

```
var website_link = document.createElement("a"); 
website_link.innerHTML = "Website";
if (my_JSON_object.website.search(/^http[s]?\:\/\//) == -1) {
    my_JSON_object.website = 'http://' + my_JSON_object.website;
}
website_link.href = my_JSON_object.website;
website_link.target = "_blank"; 
profile.appendChild(website_link);
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
your_string.replace(/href="(?!http)/, 'href="http://');
```

Example:

```
> '<a href="www.yahoo.com">Website</a>'.replace(/href="(?!http)/, 'href="http://');
"<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Website</a>"
> '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Website</a>'.replace(/href="(?!http)/, 'href="http://');
"<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Website</a>"
```

Comment: `There will be a link to website which is generated using JavaScript itself.` From this I get - no local links

Comment: My code looks like,
var website_link = document.createElement("a");
website_link.innerHTML = "Website";
website_link.href = my_JSON_object.website
website_link.target    = "_blank";
profile.appendChild(website_link);

and no local links.

Comment: I don't see where you are trying the code. You need to apply `replace` command to `my_JSON_object.website`.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrapped this functionality into the NPM module [url-schemify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-schemify):

```
var schemify = require('url-schemify');
var assert = require('assert');

// url-schemify adds default scheme (http) to the URLs that miss it

assert.equal(schemify('google.com'), 'http://google.com');
assert.equal(schemify('www.example.com'), 'http://www.example.com');

// default scheme could be configured through the options parameter

assert.equal(schemify('google.com', { scheme: 'https' }), 'https://google.com');
// { scheme: '' } will produce protocol-related URL
assert.equal(schemify('www.example.com', { scheme: '' }), '//www.example.com');

// url-schemify doesn't modify URLs that already have scheme or protocol-related ones:

assert.equal(schemify('http://google.com'), 'http://google.com');
assert.equal(schemify('https://www.example.com'), 'https://www.example.com');
assert.equal(schemify('ftp://example.com'), 'ftp://example.com');
assert.equal(schemify('//example.com'), '//example.com');
```